# How to pass a String variable from onActivityResult to another class in the same .java file

Tags: android, class, android-asynctask

I need to pass a String variable from the onActivityResult function to another class that extends an AsyncTask (`sendData`) I have written inside the same .java file. I need to pass the String variable called `js`.

Here is my code

```
public class Donate extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            PaymentConfirmation confirm =
                    data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);

            if (confirm != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, confirm.toJSONObject().toString());
                Log.i(TAG, confirm.getPayment().toJSONObject().toString());
                Log.i(TAG, confirm.getProofOfPayment().toJSONObject().toString());
                String js = confirm.getProofOfPayment().toJSONObject().toString();

                new sendData().execute(js);




                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "PaymentConfirmation info received from PayPal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                Intent conf = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PayConfirm.class);
                startActivity(conf);
            }
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "The user canceled.");
        } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
            Log.i(TAG,"An invalid Payment or PayPalConfiguration was submitted. Please see the docs.");
        }
    } 
}

public class sendData extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {


        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/shareity/paypal.php/");

        try {
            HttpEntity httpEntity = new StringEntity(js);
            httpPost.setEntity(httpEntity);
            httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            //String t = httpPost.toString();
            Log.i(TAG, "Testiing");
            Log.i(TAG, js);


        }
        catch (IOException e) {
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try this code?

Comment: @EricS. in the `sendData` class, `js` is underlined and shows the error: `js` cannot be resolved to a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the doInBackground method takes an arbitrary number of Strings.

Change your doInBackround like this:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    String js = params[0]; // The params is an array of strings :)
    // Your code here
}
```

For more information about arbitrary number of parameters see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html

Answer (score 1):

Now, access it like,

```
HttpEntity httpEntity = new StringEntity(params[0]);
```

As you have passed your `String js` to AsyncTask with,

```
new sendData().execute(js);
```

You can access this argument in `doInBackground(String... params)` with params argument. So it should be `params[0]`.

Comment: you mean replace `HttpEntity httpEntity = new StringEntity(js);` with `HttpEntity httpEntity = new StringEntity(params[0]);`? I tried it but it it still doesn't work.

Comment: yes, Just replace this code line. in `donInbackground()` `params[0]` should be your String `js`.